# Python Unittest mocking main function

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

When I try to use setUpClass method, it gives an error that _cleanups attribute is not present in the following code

```
@classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        self.argv = ['installation_tool.py']
        argv_patcher = patch.object(sys, 'argv', self.argv)
        self.addCleanup(self, argv_patcher.stop)
        self.argv_mock = argv_patcher.start()
        self.all_bears = get_all_bears_names_from_PyPI()
```

But, when I use setUp method, it works just fine, and I can add arguments like self.argv += [asd, asda, asd] in other methods.

```
def setUp(self):
        self.argv = ['installation_tool.py']
        argv_patcher = patch.object(sys, 'argv', self.argv)
        self.addCleanup(argv_patcher.stop)
        self.argv_mock = argv_patcher.start()
        self.all_bears = get_all_bears_names_from_PyPI()
```

I am trying to test the Main function here, so I need mocking to be done. How else can I test the main function?

How can I use setUpClass to do this because I need to use setUp method for other methods as they have their own start up calls?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing 'self' to setUpClass(which is a class method) instead of 'cls'. You can't use self in class methods. If u need to use setUp(instance method) somwhere else perhaps you can separate your tests in different test cases( since every test case can have its own setUp method) and run the test with the setUp you wrote, which is correct. Same applies for setUpClass. So when u are in need to define different setUp methods, you might wanna think to split test cases.